# HikariCP detects connectionleak even though all of my code has a call to close method

Tags: java, vaadin, hikaricp

I am using HikariCP in our web application and all of a sudden, I am getting this exception:

```
    [Hikari housekeeper (pool HikariPool-0)] WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@3b82d04f, stack trace follows
```

java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected

I already checked and made sure all my sql codes has a call to close method.

Here's my HikariConfig :

```
    private HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName(CLASS_FOR_NAME);
    config.setJdbcUrl(HOST);
    config.setUsername(USER);
    config.setPassword(PASS);
    config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
    config.setValidationTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(40);
    config.setMinimumIdle(0);
    config.setMaxLifetime(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2)); // 120 seconds max life time
    config.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)); // minutes
    config.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)); // millis
    config.setConnectionTestQuery("/* ping */ SELECT 1");

    return config;
}
```

here's how my queries look like :

```
   public ArrayList<LocationType> getLocationTypes() {
    ArrayList<LocationType> locationTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();

        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT\n" +
                "  location_type_id,\n" +
                "  location_type_name\n" +
                "FROM tablename;");

        resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            locationTypes.add(new LocationType(resultSet.getInt("location_type_id"), resultSet.getString("location_type_name")));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null)
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }

        if (pstmt != null)
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }

        if (connection != null)
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
    }
    return locationTypes;
}
```

I've already tried increasing the connectionLeakDetection, max connection and minimum idle but none of that solved the issue.

I have read that it could be caused by the machine(low resources) and connections being closed, I think however, none of these causes the issue.

I noticed that some long queries in my code are now being detected as connection leak, even though I am not calling their methods. I hope you guys could help.

This is the stack trace :

```
    at com..database.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:148)
at com.database.databaseServices.MileageReportService.MileageService.getMonthlySummaryBySID(MileageService.java:27)
at com.views.reports.mileage.MileageReport.lambda$generateReport$61446b05$1(MileageReport.java:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

The only line this line - MileageService.java:27, is my query to the DB and it has a close statement in its finally call.

Comment: which version of Hikari CP do you use ?

Comment: also can you please share the stacktrace which follows the log line you've posted?

Comment: I was using 2.4.3. I just upgraded today to 2.5.1 but I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: I added the stacktrace in my question @Ivan

Comment: @JRojo do you know how much time `MileageService. getMonthlySummaryBySID`? That method seem to be the culprit, not `getLocationTypes`.

Comment: @Ivan , here's the output console for getMonthlySummaryBySID : [2016-10-17 10:27:21] 3 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 677ms (execution: 544ms, fetching: 133ms) and it will only return a maximum row count of 12. Not sure why it's being detected as leak..

Comment: @JRojo and do you have a corresponding connection leak entry in your log near `[2016-10-17 10:27:21]`? What's the time on it?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to latest HikariCP.

HikariCP reports connection as leak because time taken from borrowing to close is longer than specified LeakDetectionThreshold.

Version 2.4.9 and later, it logs if connection returns after being reported as leak.

Also, looking at your config, I would tweak properties as follows
(first 4 to 1 minute and last to 5):

```
config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
config.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
config.setValidationTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));
config.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1));

config.setMaxLifetime(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5));
```

HTH

Comment: Hi Nitin, thanks for your answer. I updated my hikariconfig with the one that you suggested but the exception still occurs. I am currently using hikari 2.5.1.

Comment: after waiting a couple of minutes like 5 or so, I saw logs that the connection has returned to the pool. Even though my query's execution time does not take a second, I am not sure why it's taking a while after implementing it in my java code.

Comment: log shows connection id as well. probably put debug statements around query that you think takes second and not 5 min.